# Object Grab Moves Origin Then Mesh

Tags: modeling, origin

I duplicated an object and moved it aside but noticed that when I click on the object to move (pressing <kbd>G</kbd>) the origin moves but not the mesh.

When I confirm the move by <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd>, then the mesh moves to that location. Is there some setting I'm unaware of?

The *Affect only Origin* option doesn't do anything to remedy the problem

Running on MAC Big Sur with M1 chip. Blender Version 2.91

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more info. What kind of computer? OS? GPU? Version of Blender?

Comment: Mac is not the best match for Blender, Apple has been successfully trying to make their users and their products not compatible with the rest of the world...